# Proxy apache2 to container gives 404 error

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, apache2, flask

I am new to apache2 I've followed every tutorial on the internet, I think I've seen every question but it didnt help. The problem is that

- My container contains flask app.
- Container listens to 45654 port.
- assume my hostname is "myuni.edu" which is hosting lots of php things though apache2 rn which are available

1. `curl http://localhost:45654` from host machine works and returns html text.
2. `curl http://myuni.edu` from remote machine (my laptop) works and returns html text.
3. My */etc/apache2/sites-available/newtest.conf* file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName myuni.edu
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPass /newtest http://127.0.0.1:45654/
    ProxyPassReverse /newtest http://127.0.0.1:45654/
</VirtualHost>
```

4. */var/log/apache2/access.log* shows
   `"GET /newtest HTTP/1.1" 404 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Falkon/22.12.2 QtWebEngine/5.15.12 Chrome/87.0.4280.144 Safari/537.36"`
5. `sudo docker logs port_testing` shows only 200 requests from curl-ing localhost
6. *docker-compose.yml* file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: basic_flask_test
    container_name: port_testing
    environment:
      - SCRIPT_NAME=/newtest
    build: .
    ports:
      - "45654:5000"
```

let me know if I should provide any other details. I don't know where else to go

Comment: try ProxyPass /newtest/ http://127.0.0.1:45654/, with a slash after newtest.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu ty for the comment but it didnt work :(